# How to connect internal Bootsrap 5.2 with laravel 7

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, bootstrap-5

Hey i still learning laravel framework and i try to connect my bootstrap v.5.2 with my laravel v.7 project but it cant connect, i store css and js folder on bootsrap folder in the same level as app, config, database public, etc. and i already tried to connect it with the code:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but it still cant connect?

Comment: Assets go in the `/public` folder

Comment: where is the bootstrap assets located?

Comment: The [`bootstrap`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/9.x/bootstrap) directory has nothing to do with Bootstrap CSS. That directory is used by Laravel/PHP to load the site and relevant PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put Your bootstrap files (i.e bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js) in a new folder inside public.

Example:

```
public/css/bootstrap.min.css
public/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Then to use them in blade:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```